# I think my if else if condition does not work. Can someone help me?

Tags: javascript

Hmmm, I am practicing JS so pardon my codes. I would just like some guidance and tips to better my codes.

I created something like a registration form for runners. The conditions are:
- Early adults (race number should at or above 1000.) run at 9:30 am -  I used Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) here.
- Late adults run at 11:00 am
- Youth registrants run at 12:30 pm (regardless of registration).

Worked for youth registrants, and early adults.. but when register early birds consecutively.. the random race number won't work.

Here is my JS:

```js
let registeredEarly;
let registeredEarlyNot;
var userAge;
var userName;
const raceNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

function getValueName() {
  userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
}

function getValueAge() {
  userAge = document.getElementById('userAge').value;

  if (userAge >= 18){
    document.getElementById('showWhenAbove18').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('showWhenAbove18').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function earlyYes() {
  registeredEarly = document.getElementById('registeredEarlyYes').value;
}
function earlyNo() {
  registeredEarlyNot = document.getElementById('registeredEarlyNo').value;
}

function showResult() {

  if (registeredEarly === 'true' && userAge >= 18) {
    document.getElementById('yourResult').innerHTML = (`Hi, ${userName}! Your race number is ${raceNumber + 1000}. <br /><br /> Race will start at 9:30 AM.`);
  } else if (registeredEarlyNot === 'false' && userAge >= 18) {
    document.getElementById('yourResult').innerHTML = (`Hi, ${userName}! Your race number is ${raceNumber}.<br /><br /> Race will start at 11:00 AM.`);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('yourResult').innerHTML = (`Hi, ${userName}! Your race number is ${raceNumber}. <br /><br /> Race will start at 12:30 PM.`);
}

  document.getElementById("registerNow").reset();
  document.getElementById("showWhenAbove18").style.display = "none";
  return true;

};

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      showResult();
      event.preventDefault();
  }, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Runner Registration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Get your race number now!</h1>
    <h3 id="yourResult"></h3>

    <form id="registerNow" name="registerNow">

<label for="userName">Runner's Name</label><br />
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Enter your name" oninput="getValueName()"></input><br /><br />

<label for="userAge">Runner's age</label><br />
<input type="text" id="userAge" name="userAge" placeholder="Enter your age" oninput="getValueAge()"></input>
<br /><br />

<span id="showWhenAbove18" style="display: none;">
<label>Early Bird?</label>
<input type="radio" id="registeredEarlyYes" value="true" name="EarlyOrNot" onclick="earlyYes()">Yes
<input type="radio" id="registeredEarlyNo" value="false" name="EarlyOrNot" onclick="earlyNo()">No
<br /><br /></span>

<button type="submit" onclick="showResult()">Submit</button>

</form>
<br />
<p>Start time: <br /><br />
  Early adults (race number at or above 1000.) run at 9:30 am.<br />
  Late adults run at 11:00 am.<br />
  Youth registrants run at 12:30 pm (regardless of registration).<br /></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try "==" instead of "==="

Comment: What does "the random race number won't work." mean? What do you *expect*?

Comment: @hdeekshith and why would someone do that?

Comment: Input values are strings, so `> 18` will not do what you think.

Comment: Well, you only set `raceNumber` once, it's a constant. It won't change through the entire program execution. Instead, you might want to recalculate it whenever `getResult` executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Race number won't update because you are assigning race number in the code for first time only.

Perhaps you should assign/create a race number on clicking of `submit` button

Also no need to keep two variables to check registered early or not.

Also `input` in HTML is string, you need to convert it in integer using `Number`

```js
let registeredEarly = false;
var userAge;
var userName;
let raceNumber;

function getValueName() {
  userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
}

function getValueAge() {
  userAge = document.getElementById('userAge').value;

  if (Number(userAge) >= 18){
    document.getElementById('showWhenAbove18').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('showWhenAbove18').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function earlyYes() {
  registeredEarly = true;
}
function earlyNo() {
  registeredEarly = false;
}

function showResult() {
  raceNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  if (registeredEarly && Number(userAge) >= 18) {
    document.getElementById('yourResult').innerHTML = (`Hi, ${userName}! Your race number is ${raceNumber + 1000}. <br /><br /> Race will start at 9:30 AM.`);
  } else if (!registeredEarly && userAge >= 18) {
    document.getElementById('yourResult').innerHTML = (`Hi, ${userName}! Your race number is ${raceNumber}.<br /><br /> Race will start at 11:00 AM.`);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('yourResult').innerHTML = (`Hi, ${userName}! Your race number is ${raceNumber}. <br /><br /> Race will start at 12:30 PM.`);
}

  document.getElementById("registerNow").reset();
  document.getElementById("showWhenAbove18").style.display = "none";
  return true;

};

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      showResult();
      event.preventDefault();
      registeredEarly = false;
  }, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Runner Registration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Get your race number now!</h1>
    <h3 id="yourResult"></h3>

    <form id="registerNow" name="registerNow">

<label for="userName">Runner's Name</label><br />
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Enter your name" oninput="getValueName()"></input><br /><br />

<label for="userAge">Runner's age</label><br />
<input type="text" id="userAge" name="userAge" placeholder="Enter your age" oninput="getValueAge()"></input>
<br /><br />

<span id="showWhenAbove18" style="display: none;">
<label>Early Bird?</label>
<input type="radio" id="registeredEarlyYes" value="true" name="EarlyOrNot" onclick="earlyYes()">Yes
<input type="radio" id="registeredEarlyNo" value="false" name="EarlyOrNot" onclick="earlyNo()">No
<br /><br /></span>

<button type="submit" onclick="showResult()">Submit</button>

</form>
<br />
<p>Start time: <br /><br />
  Early adults (race number at or above 1000.) run at 9:30 am.<br />
  Late adults run at 11:00 am.<br />
  Youth registrants run at 12:30 pm (regardless of registration).<br /></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kenny! I tried registering first an adult early bird, then registered an adult not early bird.. the random race number did update but not the race time...

Comment: I believe it has something to do with capturing the value of my input radio

Comment: @porsche updated my answer and some comments. The mistakes in your code. Have a look

Comment: You're awesome! :) Thanks! I see that you negate the registeredEarly :D Hmm, one question though, can you explain to me why you put "Number" at the begin of userAge?

Comment: @porsche when you get values from input field it is string, and while doing calculation we must convert them into integers. Otherwise we will get unexpected result

Comment: You're so right, Kenny! I'll keep that in mind :) Thank you, again, so much.

Answer (score 1):

when you get the age you get text not an actual number so you need to parse it with

[parseInt() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

also if you are a beginner make sure to learn how to use the debugger those issues are easy to spot when debugging, I would read

[Get Started with Debugging JavaScript in Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I will use debugger moving forward. I am using atom code editor

Answer (score -2):

In **JavaScript** it means of the same value and type. The === operator is called a strict comparison operator, it does differ from the == operator. ... For "a == b" to evaluate to true a and b need to be the same value. In the case of "a === b" a and b must be the same value and also the same type for it to evaluate to true.